# Java : Can't display JPanel above a JLabel with image

Tags: java, swing

here's my problem : I display an ArrayList of JLabel with image and a JPanel with buttons inside a JPanel and I want to display my JPanel above my JLabel when I press a button. But when I press the button, my JPanel is under the JLabels.

Please don't tell me to use a JLayerPane cause if I can do without it it would be best.
Thanks for your solutions.

Here's an exemple of my code :
To run this put the image 100x100 found here :

http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/32190-image-very-large-when-using-the-dragging-example/

in a file named image

Main :

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setTitle("test");
    frame.setSize(900,700);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    JPanelControler ctrl = new JPanelControler();

    frame.add(ctrl.getMyJpanel());
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

MyJPanelControler :

```
public class JPanelControler {

private MyJPanel myJpanel;

public JPanelControler() {
    myJpanel = new MyJPanel();
    myJpanel.createJLabel();
    myJpanel.getButton().addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            myJpanel.displayJPanel();
        }
    });
}

public MyJPanel getMyJpanel() {
    return myJpanel;
}
```

}

MyJPanel :

```
public class MyJPanel extends JPanel {

private JButton button;
private ArrayList<JLabel> labels;
//a JPanel that contains buttons,... I won't put this class here
private JPanel panel;

public MyJPanel() {
    setLayout(null);
    button = new JButton("X");
    button.setBounds(600,600,50,50);
    add(button);
}

public void createJLabel() {
    labels = new ArrayList<>();
    JLabel label;
    try {
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("images/image.jpg"));
        for(int i=0; i<2; i++) {
            label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
            label.setBounds(i*100,50,image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
            labels.add(label);
            add(label);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void displayJPanel() {
    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(null);
    JButton b = new JButton("Ok");
    b.setBounds(0,0,100, 50);
    JButton b2 = new JButton("Cancel");
    b2.setBounds(0,50,100, 50);
    panel.setBounds(150,50, 100, 100);
    panel.add(b);
    panel.add(b2);
    add(panel);
    refresh();
}

public void refresh() {
    invalidate();
    revalidate();
    repaint();
}

public JButton getButton() {return this.button; }
```

}

Comment: Wait, are you trying to swap views? To cover the JPanel with JLabels with another JPanel?

Comment: Also, you'll want to avoid statements such as: `"Please don't tell me to use a JLayerPane cause if I can do without it it would be best. Thanks for your solutions."` -- since if that is in fact the best tool for the job, then you should use it.

Comment: It's not a swap, the JPanel I want to display is just a little JPanel that contains some buttons. But I want it above the JLabels

Comment: Also, do consider posting a valid [mcve] one with tested code that we can run (`Public`?) with a main method, and that uses easily available resources such as on-line images so that your code works in our boxes.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Ok, I will add a main if you want. While I do it, did you find something weird in my programm ?

Comment: Frustration: I'm trying to work with your code and there are so many careless errors in there, spelling issues, no return types for methods.... it's like you're trying to make it difficult for us to test your code. Please for the love of God, don't do this. Never post kind-of sort-of code here, only **real** tested code.

Comment: Please comment back once you've posted code that we can use, including using public URL for the image, including code that compiles.

Comment: I am as always in awe for the endless endless amount of patience in you Mr. Eel.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels  It's done... So do you have an idea why it doesn't work the way I want it to ?

Comment: @GhostCat  It's done... So do you have an idea why it doesn't work the way I want it to ?

Comment: `But I want it above the JLabels` - I don't know what "above" means to you. Are you talking 2Dimensions so you want the panel "North" of the labels? If so then use a proper layout manager, like a BorderLayout. You should NOT be using a null layout. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use BorderLayout]() for more information and working examples.

Comment: @camickr I didn't mean above like that. When I say above I mean it like a paper on an other. I want my JPanel to hide a bit of my JLabels. Sorry if it's not all that clear :/ If you want you can try the programm I posted you'll maybe understand better

Comment: `I want my JPanel to hide a bit of my JLabels.` - and as was suggested earlier, then you need to use a JLayeredPane which is designed to be used in 3D space so you have a Z axis to position components. Read the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Layered Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html) for working examples. Or you can use a popup JDialog. The tutorial also has a section on `How to Make Dialogs`.

Comment: Thank you for fixing the code. Down-vote removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the buttons to appear over plain images, then you have one of two options:

- Draw the images in a `paintComponent` override in the main JPanel and not as ImageIcons within a JLabel. This will allow you to add components to this same JPanel, including buttons and such, and the images will remain in the background. If you go this route, be sure to call the `super.paintComponent(g);` method first thing in your override.
- Or you could use a JLayeredPane (regardless of your not wanting to do this). You would simply put the background JPanel into the `JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER`, the bottom layer (constant is Integer 0), and place the newly displayed JButton Panel in the `JLayeredPane.PALETTE_LAYER`, which us just above the default. If you go this route, **be sure that the added JPanel is not opaque**, else it will cover over all images completely.

For an example of the 2nd suggestion, please see below:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class JPanelControler {

    private MyJPanel myJpanel;

    public JPanelControler() {
        myJpanel = new MyJPanel();
        myJpanel.createJLabel();
        myJpanel.getButton().addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                myJpanel.displayJPanel();
            }
        });
    }

    public MyJPanel getMyJpanel() {
        return myJpanel;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("test");
        frame.setSize(900, 700);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        JPanelControler ctrl = new JPanelControler();

        frame.add(ctrl.getMyJpanel());
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class MyJPanel extends JLayeredPane {

    private static final String IMG_PATH = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia"
            + "/commons/thumb/f/fc/Gros_Perr%C3%A9.jpg/100px-Gros_Perr%C3%A9.jpg";
    private JButton button;
    private ArrayList<JLabel> labels;
    // a JPanel that contains buttons,... I won't put this class here
    private JPanel panel;

    public MyJPanel() {
        setLayout(null);
        button = new JButton("X");
        button.setBounds(600, 600, 50, 50);
        add(button, JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER); // add to the bottom
    }

    public void createJLabel() {
        labels = new ArrayList<>();
        JLabel label;
        try {
            URL imgUrl = new URL(IMG_PATH); // ** added to make program work for all
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(imgUrl);
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
                label.setBounds(i * 100, 50, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
                labels.add(label);
                add(label);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void displayJPanel() {
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(null);
        panel.setOpaque(false); // ** make sure can see through
        JButton b = new JButton("Ok");
        b.setBounds(0, 0, 100, 50);
        JButton b2 = new JButton("Cancel");
        b2.setBounds(0, 50, 100, 50);
        panel.setBounds(150, 50, 100, 100);
        panel.add(b);
        panel.add(b2);
        add(panel, JLayeredPane.PALETTE_LAYER); // add it above the default layer
        refresh();
    }

    public void refresh() {
        // invalidate(); // not needed
        revalidate();
        repaint();
    }

    public JButton getButton() {
        return this.button;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, I did'nt understand why my buttons were displayed under the images but you made it clear. I will use a JLayeredPane as you advice cause I need to click on the images I display. Thanks again and sorry for my first post

Comment: @Kolopox: the Component class has a `setComponentZOrder` method as well as a `getComponentZOrder` that will help you better understand why your original code wasn't working, and even how you could possibly change it so that it does work (should you decide). Me, I'm not a big fan of `null` layouts, since that makes my later work of maintaining the code much more difficult, and so I don't use these methods much.